# Convert unix stamp to a custom format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
1384761678
```

How can I convert this to

```
/dd/mm/yyyy
```

and, in another place:

```
/dd/ *month name* /yyyy
```

Researching just keeps bringing me back to the Time.now method, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Time.at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-c-at):

> Creates a new Time object with the value given by time, the given number of seconds_with_frac, or seconds and microseconds_with_frac since the Epoch.

A unix timestamp is exactly that; a number of seconds since the Epoch.

So using `Time.at`, we can get a `Time` object from your timestamp:

```
time = Time.at(1384761678)
#=> 2013-11-18 09:01:18 +0100
```

and then we can use [Time formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) to get what you're looking for:

```
time.strftime("/%d/%m/%Y")
#=> "/18/11/2013"
time.strftime("/%d/%B/%Y")
#=> "/18/November/2013"
```